# Highlighting duplicate/unique values in ONE worksheet with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to do a comparison in Excel were I can highlight duplicate or unique values in the same worksheet. I am using this PowerShell code to do that:

```
$XL = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$XL.Visible = $false
$WB = $XL.Workbooks.Open($path)

$WB.Worksheets['Sheet1'].UsedRange.Columns[2].Cells | ForEach-Object {
    If($_.Value1 -eq $_.Value2) {
        $_.Interior.Color = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor]::rgbLightSalmon
    }
}

$WB.Save()
$XL.Quit()
```

However, that code doesn't highlight anything.

Is there a way to highlight the same values in Excel?

Comment: your if is comparing the same cell, and AFAIK, there is no property `Value1`

Comment: I think I'd go with something like `...Cells | Group-Object Value | Where {$_.Count -gt 1} | Select -Expand Group | ForEach-Object {$_.Interior.Color = ...`